# Data on two different discs

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

If I am on PlayStation 4 and I have a Minecraft disc and I buy another disc on the same PlayStation account, will the data on the first Minecraft disc still be on the second one?
Just wondering because I have a game that won't work so I was thinking about a getting another one, but at the same time I don't want to lose the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy the same game multiple times for the same console and account you'll keep the data. Your saves are not stored on the game disc so it's save to replace broken ones.

Also it's always a good idea to [make a backup](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214611/is-it-possible-to-move-minecraft-ps4-worlds-between-consoles), if you have precious data worth keeping.